# Binary Search Tree insertion - root remains null

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I'm new to Java, I want to create a Binary Search Tree class with insertion and preorder traversal, but when I finish the insertion the root object remains null and the compiler throws NullPointerException during the preorder traversal.

My node class:

```
class Node {
    int info;
    Node left;
    Node right;

    public Node() {
        info = 0;
        left = null;
        right = null;
    }

    Node(int x) {
        info = x;
        left = null;
        right = null;
    }
}
```

My Binary Search Tree class:

```
public class BinarySearchTree {

    private Node root;

    public BinarySearchTree() {
        root = null;
    }

    private void insertPrivate(Node node, int x) {
        if(node == null) {
            node = new Node(x);
        } 
        else {
            if(x < node.info) {
                insertPrivate(node.left, x);
            } 
        else if (x > node.info) {
                insertPrivate(node.right, x);
            }
        }
    }

    public void insert(int x) {
        insertPrivate(root, x);
    }

    private void preorderPrivate(Node node) {
        if(node != null) {
            System.out.println(node.info);
            preorderPrivate(node.left);
            preorderPrivate(node.right);
        }
    }

    public void preorder() {
        preorderPrivate(root);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BinarySearchTree t = new BinarySearchTree();
        t.insert(12);
        t.insert(13);
        t.preorder();
    }
}
```

Comment: I made some mistake doing the preorder traversal too. I did not check if the node is null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is a misunderstanding of Java referencing as seen with this section of code.

```
  private void insertPrivate(Node node, int x) {
    if(node == null) {
        node = new Node(x);
    } 
    ....
```

Java references are passed by value into function arguments.

Let me give you an example to clarify.

```
Node root = new Node(x);
// root == Node(x);

doSomething(root);
// Pass Node(x) into function;

void doSomething(Node node) {
    // root == Node(x);
    // node == Node(x); 

    node = new Node(y); // This updates node but not root
    // root == Node(x);
    // node == Node(y);

}
```

You are going to have to restructure your program. One way would be to have `insertPrivate` return a `Node` and assign that value to root. It is not the most efficient but it will work.

```
public void insert(int x) {
    root = insertPrivate(root, x);
}

private Node insertPrivate(Node node, int x) {
    if(node == null) {
        node = new Node(x);
    } 
    else {
        if(x < node.info) {
            node.left = insertPrivate(node.left, x);
        } 
    else if (x > node.info) {
            node.right = insertPrivate(node.right, x);
        }
    }
    return node;
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. And it includes some explanation as to why OP's version failed.  Well done.

Comment: No problem, may data structure examples are written in C++ which has the ability to pass the reference (or pointer) by reference (a.k.a double pointer) which would allow you to implement your original strategy.

Answer (score 1):

Change `insert(int x)` like this:

```
public void insert(int x) {
    if (root == nul)
        root = new Node(x);
    else
        insertPrivate(root, x);
}
```

Comment: Now it can write the value 12, but after that throws the exception.

Comment: That will not work either, it will not work for the recursive case

Answer (score 0):

Try : 
Node left = new Node();
Node right = new Node();

Answer (score 0):

You should somehow return the newly created node and assign it to the left or right node of the parent. Try this:

```
private Node insertPrivate(Node node, int x) {
    if(node == null) {
        node = new Node(x);
    } 
    else {
        if(x < node.info) {
            node.left = insertPrivate(node.left, x);
        } 
    else if (x > node.info) {
            node.right = insertPrivate(node.right, x);
        }
    }
    return node;
}
```

And your public insert function should be:

```
public void insert(int x) {
    root = insertPrivate(root, x);
}
```

Also preorderPrivate needs a null-checking:

```
private void preorderPrivate(Node node) {
    System.out.println(node.info);
    if (node.left != null)
        preorderPrivate(node.left);
    if (node.right != null)
        preorderPrivate(node.right);
}
```